# Creating number masks from number range

Tags: python, algorithm

I have a range like this:

```
1323000-1555999
```

It's is necessary to create "masks" covering entire range. So the "masks" list for range above should look like this:

```
1323***
1324***
1325***
...
14*****
...
153****
154****
1550***
1551***
```

And so on.

Anyone have ideas about how to solve this problem using Python?

The idea is to cover all range using minimum amount of masks. So in case of 1000-1999, algo should output 1*** but not 101*,102*... or 10**,11**....

Comment: Could you also share what you've tried so far?

Comment: What exactly should the masking be like? Always only the last `n` digits or some kind of pyramid shape you hinted at? If it is the latter please specify the pyramid shape more clearly.

Comment: As said, please show what you've tried and describe how exactly it's failing. It would also help to explain a bit more how the masking algorithm works. How do you determine how many digits to mask?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With a bit of looping:

#### Code:

```
def wild_card_range(start, end):
    while start <= end:
        shift = 0
        multiple = 1
        done = False
        over = False
        still_fits = True
        while not (done or over) and still_fits:
            multiple *= 10
            shift += 1
            next_value = int(start / multiple) * multiple + multiple
            done = next_value == end + 1
            over = next_value > end + 1
            still_fits = int(start / multiple) == \
                         int((start + multiple - 1) / multiple)

        if over or not still_fits:
            multiple = int(multiple / 10)
            shift -= 1
        yield str(int(start / multiple)) + '*' * shift
        start += multiple

for mask in wild_card_range(1323000, 1555999):
    print(mask)
```

#### Results:

```
1323***
1324***
1325***
1326***
1327***
1328***
1329***
133****
134****
135****
136****
137****
138****
139****
14*****
150****
151****
152****
153****
154****
1550***
1551***
1552***
1553***
1554***
1555***
```

Comment: I'll test it soon, but looks like it fits nicely! Thank you!!

Comment: Tested with several ranges, it works!
Thank you! 
Can you give me advice about which resources to use in order to improve skills of solving such tasks?

Comment: I can't mark your answer as useful because of restrictions to the noob accounts, I'll do it when I'll be able to